next.js: useSession is not a function
I have a next.js project using next-auth and I've successfully set up login and now I'm trying to use the session to get userdata on a page but when I try to use useSession() I get
TypeError: (0 , next_auth_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.useSession) is not a function
I'm running next 15.0.0-rc.0, next-auth 5.0.0-beta.19, and react 19.0.0-rc-f994737d14-20240522.
Here's the code causing the error
import Link from 'next/link';
import NavLinks from '@/app/ui/dashboard/nav-links';
import ConcordGlobe from '../concord-globe';
import { PowerIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { signOut } from '@/auth';
import { ShieldExclamationIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'


export default function Servers() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  return (
    <div className="flex h-full flex-col bg-blue-600">
      <Link
        className="mb-2 flex flex-row h-20 items-end justify-start rounded-md"
        href="/channels/me"
      >
        <div className="w-16 text-white">
          <ConcordGlobe />
        </div>
      </Link>

      
      <div className="h-auto w-full grow block"></div>
        <form
          action={async () => {
            'use server';
            await signOut();
          }}
        >
          <button className="flex h-[48px] my-3 items-center justify-center gap-2 text-white text-sm font-medium rounded-full hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-blue-600">
            <PowerIcon className="w-16" />
          </button>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}

VS Code doesn't give me any errors on this, it sees useSession as a function and even shows function information for it and everything, but pnpm run dev doesn't like it for some reason. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong or what could be going wrong and what I can do to fix it?
Note: it said type error so I tried installing @types/next-auth but that didn't help.

Just a wild guess: The docs state "Make sure that  is added to pages/_app.js.". Do you have that? https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession

rc.0, beta.19, those are versions that may break. If possible, use stable versions

Make sure you're not using a client-side hook in a server-side component. You may need to add 'use client' at the top.

I got this working on my server component:
import { auth } from "@/auth"
const session = await auth();

More info:
https://authjs.dev/getting-started/migrating-to-v5#details
